# bebop_autonomy on Raspberry Pi 2 or Odroid C2?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, bebop-autonomy, raspberrypi, parrot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone successfully used bebop_autonomy on either the Raspberry Pi 2 or the Odroid C2?  I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo installed on the Pi, but I'm running into errors because of the SSE compiler options (same problem as [this guy](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/bebop_autonomy/issues/58)).  I also have an Odroid C2 running Ubuntu 16.04, but I'm having a little trouble getting Kinetic installed, so I haven't been able to try anything on it yet.  Thanks for your help.

Edit:  I tried installing bebop_autonomy on the C2 with Kinetic, but it gives the same error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241171/bebop_autonomy-on-raspberry-pi-2-or-odroid-c2?/) by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many of the problems with incorrect compiler flags on non `x86_64` platform have been solved in the latest SDK from Parrot (`3.10.1`). I maintain a slightly patched (and leaner) version of `parrot_arsdk` [here](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/parrot_arsdk) which compiles fine on `i386` and 32-bit `arm` architectures. This patched version is released as an standalone binary and you can install it by running `sudo apt-get install ros-VERSION-parrot-arsdk` on your pi or C2 (assuming ROS repositories are setup correctly).

As of today, the released version is at version `3.9.x`. The `3.10.x` release will come out during the next ROS release (sync) cycle. You can get it from [ROS shadow-fixed repositories](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository).

At the moment `bebop_autonomy` does not use this version of `parrot_arsdk`. Instead it builds it inline during compilation. This will change soon. To see an example of how to force `bebop_autonomy` to use the packaged `parrot_arsdk`, take a look at the following branch of `bebop_autonomy`: https://github.com/AutonomyLab/bebop_autonomy/tree/2-parrot-sdk . Specifically the changes in `bebop_driver/package.xml` and `bebop_driver/CMakeLists.txt`.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2016-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0